# how to create a ken burns effect - but with image panning instead of zooming

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a ken-burns like effect for image panning - and have seen multiple examples of how to do so. but my resultant code is not working on iOS and is choppy on windows larger screens.

I am using background position - and would like to use transfrom instead - which seems to work better on iOS browsers.

```
@-webkit-keyframes pan {
0%   { background-position: 0% 0%; }
25%  { background-position: 100% 100%; }
50%  { background-position: 100% 0%; }
75%  { background-position: 100% 100%; }
100% { background-position: 0 0; }
} 


@keyframes pan {
0%   { background-position: 0% 0%; }
25%  { background-position: 100% 100%; }
50%  { background-position: 100% 0%; }
75%  { background-position: 100% 100%; }
100% { background-position: 0 0; }
} 


.back {
  background: url(big.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-animation: pan 80s ease-in 1s infinite;
          animation: pan 80s ease-in 1s infinite;
}
```

The above works in general browser but is choppy. I have tried to increase the intervals etc. - but it also does not quite work on iOS.

**how would I convert the above code to use transform or translate css-property instead ?** I understand it is better/faster for performance and smoothness.

thanks

Comment: How big are your images?  Is your PNG a PNG8 or a PNG*24?  Continuous stretching and resizing of an image is going to be a fairly large processor hit, exacerbated if your images are large.  It looks like you're just moving things around... a translate is going to less intensive than a background-position... and a translate3D should theoretically kick the hardware acceleration into play.

Comment: standard images. png24 about 300KB. sized to be 2048x1536 to support the ipads

Comment: KB doesn't matter much, what matters is decoded pixels (in this case, 2048x1538).  Your problem is in the (very strange) use of background-position -- which could be the worst property to use (I haven't profiled, though).